# How to check overlapping numbers?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table called Table1 like below,

```
Table1
------

Id         FromUnit           ToUnit
--
1,          1,                  10,

2,          5,

3,          11                  15
```

Here i need to check the overlapping number from the above table.

1)When i am inserting the first record , i can allow that insert because we dont have any record as this is a first record.

2)For the second insert 5 which is in between 1 and 10, so we should not allow that insert.

3)Third record we can insert because we dont have any previous overlapping numbers for that.

How we do this kind of check in c#? Can anybody please help me to do this ?

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Two questions, A. do you know how you going to store the data (Database \ data structs)? B.Does it have to be ordered by the Id number after you inserted the values?

Comment: Table values are given as example. i need to check before adding the second record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`BETWEEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx)

Check if the query

```
select * from Table1 where 5 between FromUnit AND ToUNit
```

returns any rows.

You should insert

```
2,          5,          5
```

instead of 
    2,          5,          NULL

to use the simple query above, otherwise you need to handle nulls in the query.

LINQ does not support the between operator, but you can compare both ends.

```
bool HasDuplicate = 
    (
    from t in context.Table1s
    where t.FromUnit <= 5
    where t.ToUnit >= 5
    select t
    ).Any();
```

But to be sure I would also implement the constraint as a database trigger.

Comment: i need to implement this "between" in C# dataTable.select() method. How we can do it ? But datatable doesnot support Between.

Comment: The question specifies that the desired answer should be in C#.

Comment: Yes i am expecting answer in C# or Linq.